# What is this handwritten character?

Tags: cantonese, character-identification

I'm trying to identify the first character in this image:

[image: unknown character followed by "口棋"]

If it helps, the pronunciation is meant to be "pong" (the whole phrase is Cantonese "pong hau kei"). I've tried looking through some Jyutping dictionaries for "pong" but I can't figure out if any of the characters match – the right-hand side seems to be significantly simplified in the handwritten version.

I believe the following two characters are "口棋", and the whole phrase is [the name of a simple game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pong_Hau_K%27i).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found this word. Please refer to: [Simplified](http://www.zdic.net/z/13/js/4981.htm) -- [Traditional](http://www.zdic.net/z/a7/js/289DC.htm)

Simplified as [䦁] while Traditional as []

1. 粵語：bong1, not "pong"
2. English Meaning: a broad hoe, a mattock

Comment: Thanks very much! That also matches another similar name which is "鋤棋" where 鋤 is also "hoe".

Comment: [link](http://www.zdic.net/z/zxjs/) Visit this website and search "邦". This page is using a, uhm... so called "character separation" method to let user to search for uncommon Chinese Character. **You're welcome!** While 鋤 does have many meanings: 鋤大弟 -- some kind of poker card game name,  鋤草(Cantonese) same as 除草 (Mandarin) -- weeding [USING spade / hoe], 鋤死你(警察用語)  -- phrase / term used by police means that police will find sufficient evidence to prove someone is / was committing a crime or breaking the law.